# How do you map a property that is a collection of strings using RestKit

Tags: restkit

I am currently using RestKit 0.20.1 to map JSON coming back from my server. I am able to map any single property and any collection of non-primitive values just fine, but I can't figure out how to map a collection of primitive properties, such as a collection of strings or integers.

For example, I am retrieving the following:

```
{
"id":3,
"name":"john",
"favorite_numbers":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

And I want to map it to an entity that looks like:

```
//MyEntity

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *identifier;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *favoriteNumbers; // This is a collection of numbers
```

How can I define a property mapping for the favoriteNumbers property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just map `favorite_numbers` to `favoriteNumbers`. Because `favoriteNumbers` is defined as an `NSArray` the values should effectively be copied directly by the mapping.

Comment: Yes, but how do I define that mapping? Just as an attribute? I will try that - I had been expecting it to be mapped as a property.

Comment: Yes, an array is just an attribute.